# MySQL query - limit results of a BLOB to 1 unique element in the blob (row)

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a query to find abandoned carts that looks like this:

```
SELECT   c.customerid, 
         c.custconfirstname, 
         c.custconemail, 
         o.ordstatus, 
         o.orddate, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(  'Order Id: ', orderid,  ' | Product name: ', ordprodname,  ' | Quantity: ', ordprodqty,  '<br>' ) AS ordered_items
 FROM    isc_customers c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_orders o ON o.ordcustid = c.customerid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_order_products op ON op.orderorderid = o.orderid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN isc_product_images pi ON pi.imageprodid = op.orderprodid
GROUP BY c.customerid
HAVING   COUNT( DISTINCT o.ordcustid ) >0
             AND o.ordstatus = 0
             AND o.orddate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -  '18000'
             AND o.orddate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -  '259200'
```

For each customer (unique customerid) The BLOB will produce something like this for ordered_items:

```
 Order Id: 15256 | Product name: PROD A | Quantity: 1
,Order Id: 15256 | Product name: PROD B | Quantity: 1
,Order Id: 15299 | Product name: PROD A | Quantity: 1
,Order Id: 15301 | Product name: PROD A | Quantity: 1
```

This can basically be interpreted that the customer has had 3 abandoned carts in the time frame. Because this query will be used to send out an abandoned cart email I don't want to spam and send an email with every product from every abandoned cart (the unique orderid) for various reasons, including that in the example above the customer has tried to put Product A in the cart 3 times over 3 orders and thus would get the item 3 times on the email.

So how can I limit the query so that it will only return the results of 1 orderid per customerid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add DISTINCT in your query and that will make it.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: This wasn't quite the solution for my problem but it would have worked other wise. I needed to add GROUP BY c.customerid, o.orderid